# Infopath email submit option opens up email client window with data and doesn't send the Email

Tags: infopath, email, infopath-data-connections

Info path email submit option opens up the email client window(Thunderbird) with the data but it is not send until we manually click on the "Send" button. Is this the default functionality of the Email Submit option.

Is there a way I can set it to send the email without the email app window opening up.?
Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the Issue .

It was because I did not have outlook configured in my machine. Once I did that, The emails were being send out automatically. 
I tested with other email clients and found that it was opening up the client applications when ever I am using an application other than Outlook.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I an not sure how you are submitting the form. I am also doing the same thing but it sends the mail in background without opening any client email application.

What i have done is :

- Click "Submit option" in "Data" menu
- In "Send form to a single desitnation" selected "Email"
- Created an Email data connection
- And used this connection as default connection.

I hope this can help you in getting rid of your problem.

Comment: I had followed the same steps. Couldn't figure out what was wrong.
Could it be because i am having Thunderbird and not outlook as my email client.?

Comment: If you are running Preview from InfoPath form than it will open the Client application, but when you will run your form from Form Library it will not open client email window. The above steps which i gave, i tested that from Form library, not from infopath preview.

Comment: I was opening the form from the library itself and it was not a preview.

Comment: I tried several ways but did not work for me. So I did this using a workflow instead. Thanks aakash for responding :)